# How does Madhvacharya interpret Bhagavad Gita sloka 18.66?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, ramanujacharya, madhvacharya

How does Madhvacharya interpret Bhagavad Gita sloka [18.66](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/18/66/)?

> **18.66** sarva-dharmān parityajya
>   mām ekaṁ śaraṇaṁ vraja
>   ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo
>   mokṣayiṣyāmi mā śucaḥ
>
> Abandon all varieties of religion and just surrender unto Me. I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.

For example, here is how Ramanujacharya interprets it in his Bhagavad Gita commentary:

> 'Relinquishing all Dharmas’ — means the complete abandonment of the notion of agency,
>   proprietorship, results etc., in the practice of Karma, Jñāna and Bhakti Yogas which are the
>   means (dharmas) for attaining the highest good when done as Divine Service.
>
> 'I will release you from all sins' — means that I will free you from all obstacles that
>   prevent you from attaining Me; consisting of [the karmic reaction of] innumerable acts of
>   doing what is forbidden and neglecting what is bidden. Accumulating from beginingless
>   times [the reactions of] these deeds cause obstacles in spiritual development.

Comment: https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-66/ Check here..

Comment: @KrishnaVarna Why is the commentary for Madhvacharya there different from what Pratimaputra has said in his answer?

Comment: I think he wrote more than 1 commentary. The one shared in answer seems to be brief commentary. Otherwise how will such important shloka be commented in just 2 lines??

Comment: Just do a Google search.. He wrote 2 commentaries..when every one commented at length, why will madhvacharya comment in just 2 lines.. Basic common sense also. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.tatvavada.org/eng/works/pdf/egbgt.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiUtcnq8KnhAhVYeysKHQcuDpAQFjAGegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw06kpasxJWUhRNygjjm262t ..jump to page 3..

Comment: @KrishnaVarna Basic common sense is not common to all.How many Acharyas wrote two commentaries?

Comment: @KrishnaVarna btw do you know the difference between commentary and subcommentary?

Answer (score 4):

Sri Madhvacharya has written a very brief commentary

> 18.66।।धर्मत्यागः फलत्यागः। कथमन्यथा युद्धविधिः।यस्तु कर्मफलत्यागी स त्यागीत्यभिधीयते [18।11] इति चोक्तम्। dharmatyAgah falatyagah. katham anyathA yiddhavidhih. yastu karmafalatyAgi sa tyAgi iti abhidhiyate (Gita 18/11). eti cha uktam.

Meaning : surrending dharma means surrendering the fruits/results. Otherwise how [can one speak of]  methods in the battle? He who renounces the fruits of karma is a real tyAgi, as says the Gita(18/11). And this is said.

Reference : https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=18&field_nsutra_value=66&scmad=1&choose=1

**UPDATE**

According to another website, Maddhva's commentary of the sloka is

> Here Lord Krishna reveals the conclusion to the essence of all knowledge. The most confidential of all knowledge that is confidential. Sarva-dharma parityagya means renouncing all conceptions of what one thinks or imagines religiosity to be. This does not mean to renounce righteousness for righteousness to all jivas or embodied beings is always attuned and in harmony with the Supreme Lord. The ultimate goal of all religious and spiritual conceptions is communion with the Supreme Lord Krishna. To achieve this one must first have realisation of their atma or immortal soul within the etheric heart. After surrendering and taking exclusive refuge in Him alone one is blessed by the Supreme Lord and by His grace, He, Himself will accomplish this for His devotee.

Reference : https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-66/

I personally however would go with the first one as I find that site to be the most authentic and it has given the original commentary in sanskrit.

**According to the pdf of the entire commentary available on https://sreenivasaraos.com/tag/gita-according-to-madhva/, it is clear that MADHVA WROTE THE FIRST ONE.**  I am also adding what is written in the 'TAtparya-nirNaya'  of the commentary as image.[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what Madhvacharya thinks about the "mām ekaṁ śaraṇaṁ vraja" part of the sloka?

Comment: Oh ok. Yeah Madhvas don't put much importance on this sloka like Sri Vaishnavas do.

Comment: This is different from his commentary listed on this site: https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-66/

Comment: Refuse to believe what?

Comment: According to @KrishnaVarna Madhvacharya wrote 2 commentaries. Check the comments in the OP.